# Error when trying to give values to matrix, shows problem with dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I made a numpy array of size 6*6*51 with the command

`matrix = np.zeros((6,6,51))`

But when I write a loop so that a 6 element array is placed in `matrix[i][:][j]` it says the

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (6) into shape
>   (51)

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: You should include a minimal example of your loop in the question.

Comment: `a = np.zeros((6,6,51)); a[1,:,1] = np.arange(6)` works. Your subscription should include all the dimensions: try `matrix[i,:,j]`

Comment: Yeah Using [i,:,j] helped. Thanks

Comment: See my answer for an explanation.

Comment: `[:]` does nothing, it's not even a place holder.  Each `[]` is evaluated sequential.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((6,6,51))
```

You are indexing incorrectly. Your subscription should include all the dimensions.

`a[i][:]` is essentially the same as `a[i]` then `j` in `a[i][:][j]` is indexing the second dimension.

```
In [14]: b = a[1][:]

In [15]: b.shape
Out[15]: (6, 51)
In [16]: c = a[1][:][1]

In [17]: c.shape
Out[17]: (51,)
```

Use `a[i,:,j]` for the subscription.

```
In [20]: a[1,:,1] = np.arange(6)
In [21]: a[1,:,1]
Out[21]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
```

---

[Numpy Indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html)